# Is there a way to get the tab label into an array? - wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I know i can use GetSelection() to get the selected tab, however it will return the tab number, i would like to get the tab label.

I am using

```
print self.GetSelection()
```

Comment: what do you mean with `having the tab label in an array` ? Do you mean a string instead? what are you talking about? a wx.Noteboox ? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suposse you are asking about a wx.Notebook as you talk about tabs.
Then use the method `GetPageText()`